# Skype for Business - Disable "ESC" Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, skype, lync, skype-for-business

Someone asked this question already but regarding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> shortcut or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTERer</kbd> (post [Disable control+enter when typing a message in Lync](https://superuser.com/questions/797337)). This is a follow up on that question.

In Skype for Business (was: lync), is it possible to stop the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key from closing a conversation or a tab in the conversation?

I assume there is a similar method as shown in the linked question, but I don't have the key value to use for <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Does anyone have it?

Answer (score 9):

I could not find the value for ESC key to put in the DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes, too.
I think that the method of using following AutoHotKey serves as a reference.

Disable Escape key in Office Communicator 2007
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/f59f12e4-3073-444d-8084-31766cab4756/disable-escape-key-in-office-communicator-2007?forum=ocsclients

The script code:

```
; stop the stupid ESC closing behavour of the IM windows
#IfWinActive ahk_class LyncConversationWindowClass
Escape::return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: I used the exact code above and it worked perfectly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I could disable the escape key behavior via the registry key, when using SfB 16.0 x64. [Note that this doesn't seem to work if you're using Skype for Business Basic]

Under `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes`:

- String Name: `Escape` (or whatever you want)
- String Value: `27,0`

The downside is that <kbd>Esc</kbd> is now disabled throughout the entire SfB app. For example, if you open a menu via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, you cannot hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it, like you could before. IMO, it's worth it.

---

Extra info: The [other post you linked](https://superuser.com/questions/797337/disable-controlenter-when-typing-a-message-in-lync) revealed the format of the string value, which appears to be:

`KeyCodeDec,Modifiers`

KeyCodeDec seems to map to [this list of virtual keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) when converted to decimal values.

With some experimentation, I've found that the modifiers are:

- `4` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- `8` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- `16` for <kbd>Alt</kbd>

You can disable pretty much any key, it seems. `70,16` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, `67,0` will prevent you from typing <kbd>c</kbd> in your chats, but will still allow <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: This is excellent. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in the situation which highlights the shared screen toolbar: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> with `32,12`, (or with 0, 4, 8, or 12). It seems this is built into the application a different way. I guess I'll need another dang AHK script.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Autohotkey script for Skype. This prevents escape key from closing the chat.

```
; stop the stupid ESC closing behavour of the IM windows
#IfWinActive ahk_class LyncTabFrameHostWindowClass
Escape::return
#IfWinActive
```

In AutoHotKey, if you right-click the taskbar icon and select "Window Spy", then click the Skype window, it will show you the akh_class name.