# How can I disable keyboard shortcut Control+Shift+S in Skype for Business (formerly called Lync)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, skype

I noticed this person had a similar issue and was able to resolve it with a regedit key to disable a specific shortcut - [Disable control+enter when typing a message in Lync](https://superuser.com/questions/797337/disable-controlenter-when-typing-a-message-in-lync).

Does anyone happen to know the key names/values for disabling <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>? Or know how I can figure out the values for various other keyboard shortcuts in Skype for Business in case something else crops up?

Currently, every time I try to Save As in Illustrator using the keyboard shortcut(<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), it ends the meeting, and I have to bug someone on the other end to turn the meeting back on, which is frustrating for everyone involved.

Comment: This will get you there, if you modify it appropriately. https://superuser.com/a/1162989/258068